# In GraphX - is there a way to pattern match on an EdgeTriplet?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

It extends Edge, which is a case class, but EdgeTriplet isn't, and it doesn't implement `unapply`. I wonder if there is a way to do pattern matching, e.g.

```
t:EdgeTriplet[Foo,Bar] match {
  case EdgeTriplet(src, dst, edgeAttr) => ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do like the following

```
(t:EdgeTriplet[Foo,Bar]) => (t.srcId, t.dstId, t.edgeAttr) match{
  case (0, 1, edgeAttr) =>
  case (stcId, dstId, edgeAttr) if ... => ...
  case _ => Unit
}
```